# Solr elevate documents only when fq constraint is explicitly used

Tags: solr, elevation

The solr elevate component only works for keyword query. In my project, I want to use elevate component to boost the documents that satisfying a custom parameter in query. For example, q=foo&fq:type=car. In this case, does anyone know how to elevate the documents with fq type car when the query is foo? It should be noted that I do not want to elevate the documents when the query is just q=foo.

Answer (score 1):

Check e.g. [Boost Score](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) OR If you are using Dismax parser check for parameter [Boost Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29)

For your condition you can try `bq=type:car^2.0`

Comment: In my project, if the type of a document is book, I do not want to elevate it. Will your approach work?

Comment: yes .. this will only boost the results higher for type car and not others.

Comment: For Solr elevation component, I only want to elevate some specific documents. I want to do something like this. <elevate>

 <query text="AAA" fq="type:car">
  <doc id="A" />
  <doc id="B" />
 </query>

</elevate>

Comment: you should use boost instead of elevation.

Comment: I just modified QueryElevationComponent to do this. The elevate.xml file can be thought as a rule table, such as "if q=foo, then elevate doc 1 and doc2". I change the QueryElevationComponent code to let it understand rule like "if q=foo and type=car, then elevate doc 1 and doc 2". It is not so hard.